# How to bind an enum to DropdownButton in Flutter?

Tags: enums, flutter, raddropdownbutton

Is it possible to bind a dropdownbutton to an enum? I have created an enum and trying to bind it to a dropdownbutton, see code below. Thanks for any help on this.

```dart
enum ClassType {
  Class-A,
  Class-B,
  Class-C,
  Class-D
}

DropdownButton<String>(
    value: classType,
    onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
            viewModel.classType = newValue;
            });
        },
    items: ClassType.map((String classType) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: classType,
            child: Text(classType),
        );
   }).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First, you need to update your DropdownButton type argument to `ClassType` and not `String`. In Dart, an enum declaration creates a new type, not Strings.

DropdownButton(...);

Next, you need to change the enum names.  An enum has to be a valid dart identifier, meaning it can't contain the symbol `-`.

```
enum ClassType {A, B, C, D}
```

I've also updated your `map` method, there is not static iterator on your enum instance, you have to list them out.  Also, you will need to convert them to Strings manually, either by calling `toString` which will give you `"ClassType.A"`, `ClassType.B"` or by writing your own function to do this.

```
return DropdownButton<ClassType>(
    value: classType,
    onChanged: (ClassType newValue) {
      setState(() {
        viewModel.classType = newValue;
      });
    },
    items: ClassType.values.map((ClassType classType) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<ClassType>(
        value: classType,
        child: Text(classType.toString()));
    }).toList();
);
```

Comment: Jonah, thanks for answering my question and providing an example. It seems like I'm not gaining value by using enum for a dropdownbutton as I have to list out all the enum item manually. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: No problem.  Unfortunately dart enums are very limited so it is often better to use strings or const objects

Comment: @EdmandLooi you can change it to ClassType.values.map. This way you don't have to list it manually.

Comment: This is the right answer but its missing the member variable classType, and the semi colon after toList() isnt needed.

ClassType classType = ClassType.A;
.... toList(),

Comment: As an alternative to classType.toString() you could use the Flutter function describeEnum(classType) which strips off the enum class name from the classType.toString().

Comment: @kafran why can't we have something that is an arbitrary representation of the enum. So that if I do EnumType.Something it prints whatever you want it to print so that we can have stuff like "Class-A" if we wanted?

Comment: I use a Map<MyEnum, String> to have ui friendly display values for my enum. Then it's just MyEnumStringMap[MyEnum] to get the string to display to the user in the dropdown.